# Is there a way to make mutation with no render return inside a function?

Tags: react-native, react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to mutate something in the graphQL backend from apollo client, but the mutation supposes to render nothing, it is just background work, I want to run it inside a function called in the constructor, like this:

```
_callUpdateTokenMutation(token: String) {
    return <Mutation mutation={REFRESH_FCM_TOKEN} variables={token}>
      {updateFcmToken => (
        return true
      )}
    </Mutation>;
  }
```

I was wondering if, there is a way to run this without a Mutation tag, something like:

```
client.mutation...
```

The thing is that the client is constructed in App.js and I want to call it in a component, is client global?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Temporally, I ended up using fetch to run the mutation in the server, something like this:

```
async _callUpdateTokenMutation(token: String) {
    const authUser = await getToken();

    if (authUser) {
      fetch(`${global.endpoint}/graphql`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: authUser
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `mutation { updateFcmToken(token: ${token}) { id } }`
        })
      })
        // .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          console.log(responseJson);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          /* TODO:
           * Leer bien el mensaje desde el servidor y mostrar la alerta
           * que manda el servidor
           */

          console.log("HOME_FCM_ERROR", error);
        });
    }
  }
```

but it would be nice if someone knows the answer with Mutation tag or something with the client.